# Angularjs: Writing Enterprise Level App with many forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on rewriting an enterprise level application which was build using older JavaScript libraries & frameworks and converting the front end to AngularJs(1.5.9) & angular ui-bootstrap. I have identified all the reusable components such as grid, tabs, modal window, tooltip etc and have come up with a folder structure for them, but i am not sure how to convert existing forms (application screens) which are in plane old HTML to angular based forms.

- Should i create separate modules, controllers, services and
  directives for each screen?
- How can i trigger a page from another?
- Should i create dependent directives for my application & forms?

I would like to know what approach is the best to convert existing HTML, jQuery & YUI based forms to AngularJs and maintain code readability & reusability

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without being opinionated, but this sounds like what [angular components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) are designed for.

Comment: I am going forward to creating components for the reusable parts of the application like data grid, tooltips, tabs etc but my question was more towards specific application business functionality. Is it worth creating components for different applications business logic or to go with simple HTML pages controlled by different controllers.